# What do you call a person who takes up a new hobby and then gives it up?

Tags: idiomatic-language, idiom-request

What do you call a person who takes up a hobby, feels very passionate about it, but then loses the passion, and takes up another hobby? For example, a person learns to sew a little, starts making dresses, skirts, etc., but then somehow loses interest and starts knitting instead, then loses interest, starts running etc. Sort of an inconsistent person, but in hobbies.
Update: Ideally, it could be used by a person to describe themselves.

Comment: Still not right but perhaps helpful - a person of short-lived interests.

Comment: It isn't the noun you're looking for but '[s/he blows hot and cold](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-blow-hot-and-cold)' describes such a person.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different terms that might apply. In English we can also express *our* feelings about someone who is doing this.

- A *Jack of All Trades* is someone who can do many things and do them well enough to be considered proficient at doing them.  This is generally a positive reference.  It was traditionally used to describe men and typically male pursuits (i.e. plumbing, carpentry, etc.) but it is more frequently being used to describe women.
- A *Dabbler* is someone who likes to a little of everything without professing to be good at anything.  This is generally a neutral reference although it can be used disparagingly.
- A *Dilettante* is someone who professes or behaves as if they are proficient at something but only possesses an elementary knowledge of the subject.  This is generally a negative reference.

You can check the synonyms of these words to find other words that might work.

Comment: I disagree with these - they all describe someone who does a little bit of everything at once, not someone who does one thing for a short time, then moves on to something else.

Comment: jack of all trades is about one's work, not hobbies, :) But I think dabbler might work pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I also believe that all these are closer in meaning to 'an amateur'. A jack of all trades means a person skillful at many things. The expression I'm looking for is closer to 'flighty', someone trying to do many things and not sticking for long.

Answer (score 1):

There is no term specific to hobbies, but you might say such a person is **fickle**, or **flighty**, meaning they are frequently changing their minds, not stable. Less common, but meaning the same is **capricious**. A person that gives up on something easily might be called a **quitter**.

All these are negative terms, most likely used to describe someone else who doesn't stick at a single thing. People tend to be more positive about themselves. A person who flits between hobbies or interests might say "I have varied interests", or "I like to try new things".

Another answer did suggest the idiom "a Jack of all trades", which doesn't describe someone who quits one thing for another, but someone who will turn their hand to anything, often badly. The full idiom is "*a Jack of all trades, but a master of none*".

Comment: Can a person say about themselves - I'm a quitter? What I'm aiming for is something neutral, a person could use to describe themselves (I didn't specify it in the question, sorry).

Comment: @rita not really - they mostly have a negative connotation. People tend to have a more positive view of themselves. I'll edit my answer.